# Upload file to box.net

Tags: xml, ajax, box-api

I'm trying to upload a file to a folder in my account on box.net. I'm using the 1.0 api version and do the upload using a post in AJAX. There's my code.

```
var fd = new FormData();

$('#files').change( function() {    
    fd.append( 'file', $('#files')[0].files[0]);
});

$( 'form' ).submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/myauth/myfolderid?share=1', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            alert(result);      
        }
    });
});
```

I want to use the XML returned to store the file id for example.
The problem is, it's never return success! I have no idea why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the version 2.0 of the API. The api has changed.